# Unable to run mosquitto_pub and sub from commad line in windows 10 getting c library runtime error

Tags: c++, mqtt, mosquitto

I've installed the mosquitto broker successfully, mosquitto service is also running but whenever I am trying to run mosquitto_pub and mosquitto_sub from command prompt it showing an error:

> an application has attempted to load the c runtime library incorrectly

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed latest version of gcc ?

Comment: yes i have installed the gcc but no success